# What is this function? $f(x)=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{{\rm sgn} (x-t)}t dt$?

Tags: integration, closed-form, regularization

What is $f(x)=\frac12\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\operatorname{sgn} (x-t)}t dt$ in closed form?

The integral should be understood as the Cauchy principal value and regularized values when diverges.

The question arose in the context of [natural integral](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/346741/prove-the-following-property-about-natural-integral).

It seems to me, the correct answer is $f(x)=\ln |x|$, but the Fourier transform method using Mathematica gives $f(x)=\ln |x| - \gamma$.

Answer (score 2):

if we split the integral we get:
$$\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{t}dt - \int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t}dt$$
using the Cauchy principal we get: 
$$\lim\limits_{R \to \infty}\int_{-R}^x\frac{1}{t}dt - \int_{x}^{R}\frac{1}{t}dt$$
$$\lim\limits_{R \to \infty}(ln(|x|)-ln(|-R|))-(ln(|R|)-ln (x))$$
R cancels out and we get:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{sgn(x-t)}{t}dt=ln(|x|)$$

Comment: Tip: put a backslash, or enclose with ```\text{}``` before commands like ```ln``` and ```sgn``` to properly format them. Example: $ln$ versus $\ln$ and $sgn$ versus $\text{sgn}$. The codes of these are ```\ln``` and ```\text{sgn}```.

Answer (score 0):

As noted bt razivo, this integral is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{t}dt - \int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t}dt
$$
It is divergent.  It diverges at $-\infty$ since it behaves like $1/t$ there.  It diverges at $+\infty$ since it behaves like $-1/t$ there.  It diverges at $0$ since it behaves like $1/t$ or $-1/t$ (or both, one on each side) there.

The correct answer to the question is: **the integral diverges**.

Now solver razivo proposes to find a "principal value" for it.  His method attempts to take care of the divergence at $\pm\infty$, but ignores the divergence at $0$.

Here is the integrand, when $x=1$:

[image: A1]

There is a jump discontinuity at $x$.  A "principal value" computation near $t=0$ will cancel the two sides, giving us a value.  But a "principal value" computation at $\pm \infty$ will not cancel.  Both sides have integral $-\infty$.  So:
$$
\mathrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(x-t)}{t}dt=-\infty
$$
This calculation is for the case $x \ne 0$.

Here is the integrand when $x=0$.

[image: A0]

This is even worse.  Not only does the integral diverge to $-\infty$ at $\pm\infty$, preventing the cancellation needed for a principal value, it also diverges to $-\infty$ at $0$, preventing the cancellation there.

But again:
$$
\mathrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(0-t)}{t}dt=-\infty
$$

---

Regularized?  I'm guessing this is what Anixx means (but there are many other possible meanings).

Assume $x>0$.  First,
$$
\mathrm{P.V.} \int_{-1}^1 \frac{dt}{t} = 0,
\tag1$$
Next, compute for $s>1$,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{-dt}{(-t)^s} = \frac{1}{s-1}
$$
The Laurent series for this in powers of $s-1$ has constant term $0$, so we substitute $s=1$ and say
$$
\mathrm{Reg}\int_{-\infty}^{-1} \frac{dt}{t} = 0
\tag2$$

Next,
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{\operatorname{sgn}(x-t)}{t^s}\;dt
=\int_{1}^x\frac{1}{t^s}dt - \int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{t^s}dt
= \frac{1-2x^{1-s}}{s-1}
$$
The Laurent series for this in powers of $s-1$ is
$$
\frac{-1}{s-1} + 2\log x + O(s-1) .
$$
So we substitute $s=1$ and say
$$
\operatorname{Reg}\int_1^{+\infty}\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(x-t)}{t^s}\;dt = 2\log x.
\tag3$$

Now, adding $(1), (2), (3)$ we have
$$
\operatorname{Reg\ P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(x-t)}{t}\;dt = 2\log x.
$$

Similarly, for $x<0$ we get
$$
\operatorname{Reg\ P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\operatorname{sgn}(x-t)}{t}\;dt = 2\log (-x).
$$

And for $x=0$ we have to regularize also at $t=0$.  I guess we now take $s<1$ to get convergence of
$$
\int_{-1}^1\frac{-1}{|t|^s}\;dt = \frac{2}{s-1}
$$
with zero constant term, so
$$
\mathrm{Reg}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{-1}{|t|}\;dt = 0
$$
However, it does seem strange to regularize with $s>1$ at $\pm \infty$ and with $s<1$ at $0$.

Comment: It seems you fail to regularize those divergencies at infinity.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot regularize because I do not know what it means.

Comment: You see, my consideration is that $\int_1^\infty \frac1x dx$ has regularized value $0$, and here is why. The harmonic series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac1k$ has the regularized value $\gamma$, but the area under it differs from the area under the integral by $\gamma$ as well: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/04/Gamma-area.svg (the blue area). So the integral must have the regularized value $0$